# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(1)+\sin^2(\frac{1}{2})+\ldots+\sin^n(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, closed-form

This was a recent problem on the [Awesome Math](https://www.awesomemath.org/mathematical-reflections/archives/#toggle-id-2) Problem Column. The [solution](https://www.awesomemath.org/mathematical-reflections/archives/#toggle-id-1) is given as follows:

We shall use [Stolz-Cesaro Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). We have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(1)+\sin^2(\frac{1}{2})+\ldots+\sin^n(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^n(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^n(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n^n}}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}.$$
Since
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}<\frac{1}{n}$$
we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$$
So, the required limit is $0$.

I have two problems with the given proof that I can’t wrap my head around.

Firstly, from everything I have read so far the Stolz-Cesaro limit only applies to cases where the limit is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ and the form $\frac{\cdot}{\infty}$. However, just from the wording of the theorem and the way the author presented this solution both seem to imply the following:
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^k\Big(\frac{1}{k}\Big), \ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \ b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$
Then when “applying” the Stolz-Cesaro theorem you would have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin^k(\frac{1}{k})-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin^k(\frac{1}{k})}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^n(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n!}}$$

The problem that I see is when $n\to\infty$ we know that $a_n$ converges by the root test, and $b_n$ converges to $e-1$. So by basic limit rules this would converge also. So it seems that $b_n$ does not satisfy either of the sequence requirements of the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem.

Secondly, according to wolfram $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^n\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\approx 1.11043$. So intuitively it seems to me that this limit would be approximately $\frac{1.11043}{e-1}\approx 0.646244$.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: It seems to me that the limit would easily be shown to be at least $\sin(1)/(e-1)$ since the numerator and the denominator are sums of positive numbers, the denominator converging to $e-1$. — Perhaps the website has a typo and they intended each power of $\sin(k)$ to have an exponent of $n$?

Comment: That would explain why the limit would be $0$. However, they seemed to be very thorough with how they wrote the limit.

Comment: I agree. I think the author has an incorrect “solution” and that what you have done is correct instead. I was just considering the idea because I didn’t know the S-C Lemma very well, but my suggestion wouldn’t work for how they applied the lemma.

Comment: It appears that they are not that *awesome*.

Comment: When in doubt always trust math.se. It's not that there are no mistakes on this website, but the community is active enough to fix mistakes soon.

Comment: As you stated, you can not apply Stolz–Cesàro theorem, since one of the inputs to the theorem is "Assume that $(b_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is a strictly monotone and **divergent sequence**".

Answer (score 1):

*Note sure that this is a valide answer.*

Let
$$a_k=\sin ^k\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\implies \log(a_k)=k \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)$$ Using Taylor
$$\log(a_k)=-k \log (k)-\frac{1}{6 k}-\frac{1}{180 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$
$$a_k=k^{-k}\,\exp\left(-\frac{1}{6 k}-\frac{1}{180 k^3}+\cdots \right)$$ The summation of the $a_k$'s from $k=1$ to $n$ converges very fast to $1.110750$ which, divided by $e-1$ gives $0.646431$ while the result should be $0.646242$. Adding the next term in the exponential (namely $-\frac{1}{2835 k^6}$)  would give $0.646256$ and so forth since all terms in the exponential are negative.

Notice that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-k}=1.2912859970626635404\cdots$$ is a well know number (have a look [here](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.2912859970626635404&lookup_type=simple)). Forgetting the exponential term, this would give an upper bound equal to $\frac 34$ for the limit.